# convert multiple strings from selenium and Beautiful soup to CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, string, selenium, csv

I have this scraper I am trying to export as a csv file in Google Colab. I received the scraped information as a string value, but I cannot convert it to a csv. I want each scraped attribute "title", "size", etc to populate a column in a csv file. I have ran the strings through Beautiful soup to remove the HTML formatting. Please see my code below to help.

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import io
from io import StringIO
import csv
#from google.colab import drive
#drive.mount('drive')
#Use new Library (kora.selenium) to run chromedriver 
from kora.selenium import wd
#Import BeautifulSoup to parse HTML formatting
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
wd.get("https://www.grailed.com/sold/EP8S3v8V_w") #Get webpage

ScrollNumber=round(200/40)+1
for i in range(0,ScrollNumber):
  wd.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
  time.sleep(2)

#--------------#
#Each new attribute will have to found using XPATH because Grailed's website is written in Javascript (js.react) not HTML
#Only 39 results will show because the JS page is infinite scroll and selenium must be told to keep scrolling.
follow_loop = range(2, 200)
for x in follow_loop:
  #Title 
    title = "//*[@id='shop']/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div["
    title += str(x)
    title += "]/a/div[3]/div[2]/p"
    title = wd.find_elements_by_xpath(title)
    title = str(title)
  #Price 
    price = "//*[@id='shop']/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div["
    price += str(x)
    price += "]/div/div/p/span"
    price = wd.find_elements_by_xpath(price)
    price = str(price)
  #Size 
    size = "//*[@id='shop']/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div["
    size += str(x)
    size += "]/a/div[3]/div[1]/p[2]"
    size = wd.find_elements_by_xpath(size)
    size = str(size)
  #Sold 
    sold = "//*[@id='shop']/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div["
    sold += str(x)
    sold += "]/a/p/span"
    sold = wd.find_elements_by_xpath(sold)
    sold = str(sold)
  #Clean HTML formatting using Beautiful soup
    cleantitle = BeautifulSoup(title, "lxml").text
    cleanprice = BeautifulSoup(price, "lxml").text
    cleansize = BeautifulSoup(size, "lxml").text
    cleansold = BeautifulSoup(sold, "lxml").text
```

Comment: Your code is currently saving the webelement instead of the text inside it. I think there are some fundamental errors in your code. If you let me know you're still here, I'll just rewrite it for you

Comment: @Mick yes please rewrite it if you can.

Comment: Ok, give me 15-30 mins

Comment: Awesome appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

This was a lot of work lol

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import csv

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.grailed.com/sold/EP8S3v8V_w")

scroll_count = round(200 / 40) + 1
for i in range(scroll_count):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
    time.sleep(2)

time.sleep(3)

titles = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("p.listing-designer")
prices = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("p.sub-title.sold-price")
sizes = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("p.listing-size.sub-title")
sold = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.-overlay")

data = [titles, prices, sizes, sold]

data = [list(map(lambda element: element.text, arr)) for arr in data]

with open('sold_shoes.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    j = 0
    while j < len(titles):
        row = []
        for i in range(len(data)):
            row.append(data[i][j])
        writer.writerow(row)
        j += 1
```

I'm not sure why it makes a newline between every row in the file, but I assume it's not a problem. Also, it's a naïve solution in that it assumes the size of each list is the same, consider using one list and making new lists from the child elements of the parent. Also, I just used Selenium without BeautifulSoup because it's easier for me, but you should learn BS too because it's faster for scraping than Selenium. Happy coding.

Comment: Good Answer. I'd use dict writer though.